# .htaccess redirect taking site to "Index of" page instead of redirecting to specified domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I recently modified my .htaccess file's redirects. The reason for this was because my my old file's individual `RedirectPermanent` links that point at specific pages were not working. This is because previously I had the wildcard code on top. The only thing that was working was my main redirect from this.

With the new code, I tried to putting the `RedirectPermanent` code on top. Now nothing is redirecting at all. When going to the site, I get the "Index of" page (see img below).

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong with my new code for this to not work?

[image]

Newest - not redirecting

```
RewriteEngine On

# These redirects must execute first,
# there are url changes on destination server

RedirectPermanent /about-us.html  https://newdomain.com/about
RedirectPermanent /about-us/t-slotted-aluminum-profiles.html  https://newdomain.com/profile
RedirectPermanent /about-us/t-slot-nuts-fasteners.html https://newdomain.com/components
RedirectPermanent /about-us/customer-service.html  https://newdomain.com/about

# Now that there are no more url changes, 
# Wildcard everything else to new domain

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldDomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https:/newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Previous Code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldDomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/administrator [NC]

RedirectPermanent /about-us.html  https://newDomain.com/about
RedirectPermanent /about-us/t-slotted-aluminum-profiles.html  https://newDomain.com/profile
RedirectPermanent /about-us/t-slot-nuts-fasteners.html https://newDomain.com/components
RedirectPermanent /about-us/customer-service.html  https://newDomain.com/about

RewriteRule ^ https://newDomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing something. Try this

```
RewriteEngine On 

# These redirects must execute first,
# there are url changes on destination server

RedirectPermanent /about-us.html  https://newdomain.com/about
RedirectPermanent /about-us/t-slotted-aluminum-profiles.html  https://newdomain.com/profile
RedirectPermanent /about-us/t-slot-nuts-fasteners.html https://newdomain.com/components
RedirectPermanent /about-us/customer-service.html  https://newdomain.com/about

# Now that there are no more url changes, 
# Wildcard everything else to new domain

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newDomain\.com 
RewriteRule (.*) https://newDomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```